# Matching pattern using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string, and I want to extract a specific line from that entire string by using Regex.

This is my string:

```
Physical interface: rt90, Enabled, Helical link is Up
Interface index: 178, SPMZ ifIndex: 980
Description: 4&109G LAG to kah7zt84
Link-level type: Ethernet, XCU: 9082, Speed: 10Gbps, BPDU Error: Hello,
Wind-REWRITE Error: None, Loopback: Disabled, Source filtering: abled,
Flow : abled
Pad to min frame size0: Disabled
Minimum li needed: 1, Minimum bandwidth need: 0bps
Device flags   : Running
Interface flags: RTYU-Traps Internal: 0x40
Current address: 1e:pb:i0:90:10:76, Hardware address: 1e:pb:i0:90:10:768
Last flapped   : 2017-12-16 32:12:12 GMT (3d 16:16 ago)
Input rate     : 115 bps (20 pps)
Output rate    : 8 bps (1 pps)`
```

I want to extract the following line:

```
Physical interface: rt90, Enabled, Helical link is Up
```

(The first line)

Can someone help, please?
Thanks.

Comment: You want to retrieve only the first line? Try /^.*$/

Comment: `line = mystring.splitlines()[0]`.

Comment: Yes @nageeb. I want to extract the first line.

Comment: Hi @nageeb thanks for the answer. But everytime, this might not be the first line, that's the reason I wanted to use Regex.

Comment: Then you need to provide more information.  What is the pattern that you need to recognize in order to match with regex? eg: is it always the "Physical Interface" line?

Comment: Yes, always "Physical Interface line". @nageeb. Thanks.

Comment: /^Physical Interface.*$/

Comment: Next time, take the time to well explain your problem. It seems that Laurent Laporte answer solve your problem (without using regex, that is a good news).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the first line which starts with `Physical interface’, you can use:

```
lines = text.splitlines()
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("Physical interface"):
        print(line)
        break
else:
    print('Not found')
```

Comment: @Adrija: if you find this answer useful, don't forget to upvote it.

Comment: I did mark it right @Casimir et Hippolyte.

Comment: @Adrija: I was speaking about an upvote, not about accepting it. For instance, your question were downvoted three times, and the answer was upvoted one time (by me). I think you can also upvote it since it solve your problem.